# Create a point on a phase portrait and draw a trajectory flow following the vector lines by time-passing

Tags: plotting, dynamic, interactive

I wrote a simple 2D-phase portrait sample and still have a unsolvable question about adding a new feature on the plot. Specifically, I would like to drop down a point on the plot by each mouse-click and let it run down the vector stream as defined in the code. Here is the definition:

```
Vdot[V_, W_, Current_, a_] := V (a - V) (V - 1) - W + Current;
Wdot[V_, W_, b_, c_] := b V - c W;
pstream[{Xcenter_, Ycenter_, MagFactor_}, Current_, a_, b_, c_] := 
  StreamPlot[{Vdot[V, W, Current, a], Wdot[V, W, b, c]}, {V, 
    Xcenter - 2.5/(2*MagFactor), Xcenter + 2.5/(2*MagFactor)}, {W, 
    Ycenter - 1/(2*MagFactor), Ycenter + 1/(2*MagFactor)}, 
   PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", StreamStyle -> Gray];
pcontour[{Xcenter_, Ycenter_, MagFactor_}, Current_, a_, b_, c_] := 
  ContourPlot[{Vdot[V, W, Current, a] == 0, 
    Wdot[V, W, b, c] == 0}, {V, Xcenter - 2.5/(2*MagFactor), 
    Xcenter + 2.5/(2*MagFactor)}, {W, Ycenter - 1/(2*MagFactor), 
    Ycenter + 1/(2*MagFactor)}, 
   ContourStyle -> {Directive[Orange, Dashed], 
     Directive[Blue, Dashed]}];
pnorm[{Xcenter_, Ycenter_, MagFactor_}, Current_, a_, b_, c_] := 
  DensityPlot[Sqrt[
   Vdot[V, W, Current, a]^2 + Wdot[V, W, b, c]^2], {V, 
    Xcenter - 2.5/(2*MagFactor), Xcenter + 2.5/(2*MagFactor)}, {W, 
    Ycenter - 1/(2*MagFactor), Ycenter + 1/(2*MagFactor)}, 
   PlotTheme -> "Detailed", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
   PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.75]];
Showbox2D[{Xcenter_, Ycenter_, MagFactor_}, Current_, a_, b_, c_] := 
  Show[pnorm[{Xcenter, Ycenter, MagFactor}, Current, a, b, c], 
   pstream[{Xcenter, Ycenter, MagFactor}, Current, a, b, c], 
   pcontour[{Xcenter, Ycenter, MagFactor}, Current, a, b, c], 
   GridLines -> Automatic];
```

Plot sample:

[image: PlotSample]

Anyone got an idea for breakthrough? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do this using a `Manipulate` with a `Locator` pane, because that's easier than using an `EventHandler` for mouse clicks.

First, define a function that calculates the additional stream line that you need, then superimpose that onto the already existing plots:

```
linePlot[V_, W_, Current_, a_, b_, c_, tMax_] := Module[{x, y},
  NDSolveValue[{D[{x[t], y[t]}, t] == {Vdot[x[t], y[t], Current, a], 
      Wdot[x[t], y[t], b, c]}, x[0] == V, y[0] == W}, {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, tMax}]]

interactiveBox2D[{Xcenter_, Ycenter_, MagFactor_}, Current_, a_, b_, c_, tMax_] := 
 DynamicModule[{static = 
    Showbox2D[{Xcenter, Ycenter, MagFactor}, Current, a, b, c]},
  Manipulate[
   Show[
    static,
    ParametricPlot[
     Evaluate@linePlot[x[[1]], x[[2]], Current, a, b, c, tMax], {t, 0, tMax}, 
       PlotStyle -> Red]], {x, {Xcenter - 2.5/(2*MagFactor), 
     Ycenter - 1/(2*MagFactor)}, {Xcenter + 2.5/(2*MagFactor), 
     Ycenter + 1/(2*MagFactor)}, Locator}]]

interactiveBox2D[{0, .4, 1}, 1/2, 1, 1, 1, 10]
```

[image: manipulate]

In the functions `interactiveBox2D` and `linePlot`, I added an additional parameter `tMax` that says how long the flow line will be in terms of its parameter `t`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and sorry for being late.